# How to show that there is a number at which the truncated Taylor Series is exact?

Tags: taylor-expansion, central-limit-theorem

So, I'm reading an "easy" proof of the Central Limit Theorem in the book Probability and Mathematical Statistics, by Sahoo, and there is a point where the moment generating function is expanded in a Taylor series about $t=0$

$$M(t) =M(0) + M'(0)t + \frac{1}{2} M''(\eta)t^2$$
with $\eta\in(0,t)$

So my question, where did that $\eta$ come from?

It's basically saying that 
$$\frac{1}{2} M''(\eta)t^2 = \frac{1}{2} M''(0)t^2 + \mathcal{O}(3)$$

It has the looks of a mean value theorem to me, but I cannot seem to connect the two.

Also, I didn't know how to better phrase the question. I suspect that if I did I could have pulled the correct theorem to breach the gap

Comment: It is a standard theorem about power series in general.  The fact that you are dealing with a moment generating function is irrelevant.

Comment: The remainder is called the Le-Grange remainder for a Taylor series.